# Nginx + FastCGI + SSI : include virtual local URL not working

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, ssi

I am using Nginx with FastCGI for Php and the native module Nginx SSI.

In my home.php file, if I write this :

```
<!--# include virtual="robots.txt" -->
```

It works, I have the content of the STATIC file /robots.txt on my screen. But I i try a "dynamic" URL (which call the fastcgi, it doesnt work (I get "subrequests cycle while processing" in error.log)

```
<!--# include virtual="toto.php" -->
```

Where toto.php just print some HTML stuff .... I know Nginx shares memory between main query and sub requests, is it bug with FastCGI ?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve it? thanks